# Python socket Connection hold on Server if the Client stopp

Tags: python, sockets, server, connection, client

my quastion is how i can holt the connection form the server if the client break(stopp).

```
BUFSIZE = 1024
name = "intents"


def main():
    # Socket erstellen und an Port binden
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind(('127.0.0.1', ECHO_PORT))
    s.listen(10)
```

Comment: (cs,adress) = s.accept()
    print('Verbunden mit %s:%s' % (cs,adress))

Comment: data = cs.recv(BUFSIZE)
        data = data.decode()
        print("Empfange:"+data)

Comment: the code vorm the server ^

Comment: Please don't add comments to clarify, [edit] your question instead. Comments appear in order of votes or may get deleted. Put everything in one place, the question.

Comment: Why would you want to keep the connection open? You'd be leaking connections. If the client wants to come back, you can create a new connection. That way the client doesn't need to remember the old connection.